# Combine input fields with javascript output and send it with wp_mail

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, sendmail

My website is almost fully functional with a calculator, styled with CSS, and it updates/calculates with JavaScript commands.

Users that visit my site can calculate the volume of physical objects. Whatever the input will be calculated with my JavaScript function. My site is made with WordPress, and my calculator is created as a plugin.

After they have done their calculations, a variable in my JavaScript file is being populated with a simple string (the sum of the calculations) which I output to a `<div>`.

Below this calculator is a custom form that can be filled in by the user, and a "send mail" button at the end.

The whole `calculator.php` file is basically a function that is called with a shortcode on the site.

I want to combine the information from the calculator (the simple JavaScript string variable 'sum') with the information from the custom form, and when they click the "send" button, this will all be sent to my email address in HTML format.

I have successfully combined the 'sum' and the 'form' data into one JavaScript variable (this is executed when I click the 'send mail' button), but I don't know how to get this content back to PHP and add it to the 'body' of `wp_mail()`.

**EDIT**
I basically need help with how to send an email from my script including a string from my JavaScript file.

```
//main.js
    var myString = "this is the text I want to include in the body of my mail";

    function processForm(){
    // call the php function 'sendMail()' and send 'myString' to be used as $body
    }

//calculator.php
<button type="button" class="submit_btn" onClick="processForm()">Send mail</button>

function sendMail(){
  $to = 'example@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'The subject';
  $body = //use JS variable here (myString)
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
```

Do I use AJAX, JQuery, JSON, SESSIONS, COOKIES? I don't know what the best practice is, and would really appreciate some help here. All these terms confuse me to be honest.
I know PHP is server side, and JS is client side, so I know I need to do something fancy here to make this code work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is expected that you do some research and make an attempt at writing the code yourself. If you have a specific question about your code, include the relevant code and details of the problem in your question.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post with a better question and some example code from my project. The whole file is not relevant to include, as it is just a long list of calculations and html outputs. This stripped version explains my issue. I know this should be an easy task to do, which makes it even more frustrating for me.